# What CSS styles go where when styling the Nav Bar

Tags: css, html-lists, navigationbar, pseudo-class

While working on the navigation of my first website recently, I've been quite confused about which styles go where when it comes to a:link and the :hover pseudo class.

Here's my code for a better explanation:

```
#header_nav ul li {
    font-family: "Futura Bk BT";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#header_nav ul li a:link, #header_nav ul li a:visited {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family: "Futura Bk BT";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 35px;
}

#header_nav ul li:hover a {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family: "Futura Bk BT";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #B40000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 35px;  
}
```

As you can see, except for a few additions and exclusions, the code for all 3 of the ID's is the same. This is because I've had seemingly random results when trying to style each individually and so I've found that its just easier to replicate everything, over and over so that nothing is missed out however this method is becoming increasingly confusing as my StyleSheet expands with new pages.

So my question to you experienced developers is: What CSS styles should go where when customising links?

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is mostly depending on other CSS rules, that probably apply to your links. So if you get "random results", look in your web inspector for other rules, that may overwrite your rule set here.

Some hints:

- `list-style-type: none;` doesn't make sense on an `<a>` tag, it's only applied to `<ul>` or `<ol>`
- It's probably sufficient to set `text-decoration: none;` only for the `<a>` tag
- if you don't want to duplicate all rules but need the rules in a child tag, you can use `inherit`

I would write your code as follows (untested):

```
#header_nav ul li {
    font-family: "Futura Bk BT";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#header_nav ul li a:link,
#header_nav ul li a:visited {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 35px;
}

#header_nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #B40000;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Depending on your markup, you can set rules like `font-family`, `font-size` and `color` directly for the `<a>` tag, if there is no need to have them in `<li>`.